# get java_home value from servers with bash script

Tags: shell, ssh, environment-variables, echo, java-home

I'm confused. I want find JAVA_HOME value in server and type this code in bash script.

```
ssh username@server "echo ${JAVA_HOME}"
```

and try

```
ssh username@server "echo $JAVA_HOME"
```

or

```
 ssh username@server 'echo $JAVA_HOME'
```

and all of they not worked;

I replace "JAVA_HOME" with "PATH" and it's work;
I connect with ssh to server and try "echo $JAVA_HOME " and it's work.
I think the problem is "_" and I don't know how fix it.
please help me

Comment: I don't think that the problem is `_` but rather that `JAVA_HOME` is not set in the environment you SSH into (hint: interactive shell vs. non-interactive shell). Use `set` to see *all* defined environment variables.

Comment: I used "set" and JAVA_HOME is defined.

Comment: did you call `set` from an interactive shell or exactly as you'd called `echo` (i.e. `ssh username@server 'set'`)?

Comment: In interactive JAVA_HOME is defined but in non-interactive is not defined.

Comment: well, then there's your problem. You need to check the appropriate initialization files of your shell to see where it's defined and where it *should* be defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not feasible.

$JAVA_HOME will be interpreted to the variable value in localhost instead of the remote server.
Besides, executing by ssh is not a login shell, you will not get environment variables defined in /etc/profile